# What was McCormick Country Chicken Bag Seasoning?

Tags: substitutions, chicken, seasoning, gravy

My family loved McCormick Country Chicken Bag Seasoning. They would request it on the menu by name and there were rarely left overs. And I loved how simple it was to mix the seasonings with water and pour over bone in chicken pieces and fresh green beans that were arranged in an oven bag, tie up and bake. It would make a creamy gravy that was amazing spooned over rice. Unfortunately, McCormick decided to discontinue the item in 2016. I have tried their original chicken bag flavor they still offer, tried alternate chicken in gravy recipes, tried McCormick recipes for Slow cooker country chicken stew and absolutely nothing is the same as that creamy country style gravy. Does anyone have a good "copycat" recipe that can substitute for this product?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Recipe requests are off-topic, so this is likely to be closed. I'd bet there's copycat recipes on the web available with a google search, if not you could ask how to recreate the effect you want. If you'd like to do that you'll need to edit and add the recipe you're having a problem with.

Comment: Have you considered thinking about the [ingredient list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpRgx.png)? While you might not be excited about modified food starch, mono and di-glycerides, and soy lecithin, they are available to purchase separately or you could think about alternatives.